# I am having a algebra exam soon I found this on an exam paper and have no Idea how to do it. Can anyone help

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We say that a matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ is orthogonal if $\mathbf{Q}^T = \mathbf{Q}^{−1}$, recall $\mathbf{Q}^{T}$ is the transpose of $\mathbf{Q}$. Show that the dot product of any two vectors $\vec{u},\vec{v}∈\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathbf{u}^{T}\mathbf{v}$. Prove the following, given a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and vectors $\vec{u},\vec{v}∈R^n$ such that: $$\mathbf{A}\vec{u}\cdot\mathbf{A}\vec{v}=\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$$ then $\mathbf{A}$ is orthogonal. ( hint: you can assume that $(\mathbf{AB})^{T}=\mathbf{B}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{T}$)

Comment: Another hint: show us what you've done so far, your ideas, insights, self effort...

Comment: The statement is false as it is written. With quantification ranging over the proper sets, what you're trying to prove is $$\forall A\forall u,v\left[Au\cdot Av=u\cdot v\implies AA^T=I\right].$$ This is false. Just take $A$ the null matrix and $u,v$ the null vectors. Clearly the antecedent holds and the consequent does not. Correct is $$\forall A[\forall u,v(Au\cdot Av=u\cdot v)\implies AA^T=I].$$ **Edit:** On a second reading, I don't think the statement is wrong, rather it is ambiguous. You should be wanting to prove the last formula above, not the first.

Comment: To clarify what Git Gud is saying, suppose $\vec{u} = 0$ and $\vec{v} = 0$.  Then you don't know _anything_ about $A$, since the statement becomes $0 = 0$.  The problem would be better stated "Given a matrix A, with the following property of all pairs of vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$:" etc

Answer (score 2):

Let ${ u}=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)^T$ and $v=(v_1,\ldots v_n)^T$ then we have
$$u^T v=\sum_{k=1}^n u_kv_k=\langle u,v\rangle=:u\cdot v$$
moreover if we have for all $u,v\in \Bbb R^n$

$$Au\cdot Av=u\cdot v\iff (Au)^T(Av)=u^Tv\\\iff u^TA^TAv=u^Tv\iff A^TA=I_n\iff\text{$A$ is orthogonal}$$

**Edit** To justify the equivalence $u^TA^TAv=u^Tv\iff A^TA=I_n$ notice that
$$q(u,v)=u^TA^TAv$$
is a quadratic form and by the unicity of its matrix in a given basis we conclude the result.

Comment: The equivalence $u^TA^TAv=u^Tv\iff A^TA=I_n$ is obviously false. Correct is $\forall u,v(u^TA^TAv=u^Tv)\iff A^TA=I_n$. And in my opinion this equivalence isn't shallow enough not to be justified.

Comment: I said that this is for all $u,v\in\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. As it is written, you're asserting $\forall u,v(Au\cdot Av\iff AA^T=I_n)$. This simply isn't true.

Comment: Sorry my logic is correct: 
$$\forall u,v,\quad Au\cdot Av=u\cdot v\iff AA^T=I_n$$

Comment: @GitGud I'm not sure what the problem here is? Are you simply stating that $$u^{T}\mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{A}v=u^{T}v \iff \mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{I}_{n}$$ Is not true $\forall \vec{u},\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ because if $\vec{u} = \vec{0} \lor \vec{v}=\vec{0}$ the iff does not hold? Forgive me, but this feels like an edge case which can be discarded?

Comment: @Shaktal An example is that choice of vectors, yes. Others might exist, depending on $A$. Read my first comment in this question. **Edit:** Seeing your comment's edit, here is mine: as I said in the first part of this comment, there might be other choices - non trivial ones - that make the equivalence false.

Comment: @Shaktal Let me comment on another matter. I noticed you edited the question and changed the notation. Please read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11857/arbitrarily-editing-an-askers-notation-to-fit-your-own-preferences).

Comment: @GitGud Forgive my ignorance of set theory (I've had no formal training) but I fail to see what the difference between the two statements: $$\forall u,v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}(u^{T}\mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{A}v=u^{T}v)\iff \mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{I}_{n}$$ And: $$u^{T}\mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{A}v=u^{T}v \iff \mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{I}_{n}\qquad \forall u,v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$$ could be? And how did I change the meaning of the OPs question, I simply added the overarrow notation which surely didn't change the meaning of the question? (The OP had stated $\vec{u},\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$)

Comment: @Shaktal The second formula isn't a good way to write things, but usually one translates it to $$\forall u,v\left[Au\cdot Av=u\cdot v\implies AA^T=I\right].$$ Now let me forward you to [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813580/i-am-having-a-algebra-exam-soon-i-found-this-on-an-exam-paper-and-have-no-idea-h#comment1681343_813580).

Comment: @Shaktal Regarding your edit, you didn't change the meaning, you changed the notation to fit your own preference and that's what the linked thread talks about.